# TikZ drawing triangulation

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can anyone help reproducing this on TIKZ?

[image]

Comment: What shape is outer line= A regular pentagon or some irregular shape?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always show us, what you try yourself to solve your problem (the best in form of MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small complete document, which we can test in our computers as it is. So far your question is demand *do-this-for-me* which is not appreciated here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a solution with two foreach loops

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \aa in {0,1,2,...,5}{
    \draw (0,0)coordinate(O) -- ({\aa*360/5}:2)coordinate(P\aa);
}

\draw 
(P0) 
\foreach \aa in  {1,2,...,5}{--
(P\aa)
}
-- cycle;
\draw[fill] (O) circle (1mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good....and I always approved these methods. I use mathcha often when the user are without MWE.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed \draw to draw[rotate=18] and it's perfect for me too

Comment: @Random Oh no I'm glad you know something new about it. With humility I will give the green tick to rpapa that is the right way to know TikZ.

Answer (score 4):

A fast solution that you can create yourself with a tool called [mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw   (259.15,107.06) -- (342.34,167.5) -- (310.57,265.29) -- (207.74,265.29) -- (175.97,167.5) -- cycle ;
%Straight Lines [id:da5500931558328854] 
\draw    (259.15,107.06) -- (259.15,194.53) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9807314972174233] 
\draw    (175.97,167.5) -- (259.15,194.53) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4619344120764781] 
\draw    (342.34,167.5) -- (259.15,194.53) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da9720784168022731] 
\draw    (259.15,194.53) -- (207.74,265.29) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3200168995877415] 
\draw    (259.15,194.53) -- (310.57,265.29) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp3653706700614776] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (254.65,194.53) .. controls (254.65,192.04) and (256.67,190.03) .. (259.15,190.03) .. controls (261.64,190.03) and (263.65,192.04) .. (263.65,194.53) .. controls (263.65,197.02) and (261.64,199.03) .. (259.15,199.03) .. controls (256.67,199.03) and (254.65,197.02) .. (254.65,194.53) -- cycle ;
\draw (268,190.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {\large $A_{i}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help. I didn't know about matchcha, i will be using it for complex finite element mesh

Comment: @Random Thank you very much for to have switch the green mark :-)

Answer (score 2):

If drawn shape is regular pentagon, than I would exploit TikZ library `regular polygon` (see TikZ and PGF manual, pp 792, version 3.1.7a):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14159]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (s)   [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=5, draw,
             minimum size=33mm] {$\bullet$};
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}
    \draw (0,0) -- (s.corner \i);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]